# Showing duplicate cells in UITableView via NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am querying Core Data to find the "OLDEST" and "HEAVIEST" amongst a group of people. With a larger dataset this usually works (as the chance of a duplicate match is less), but with a small dataset where the OLDEST person may also be the HEAVIEST I am having problems.

```
[John, 77, 160]
[Pete, 56, 155]
[Jane, 19, 130]
[Fred, 27, 159]
[Jill, 32, 128]
```

As I want to display this information in 2 `UITableViewCell`s of a `UITableView` I am doing this by first running 2 `NSFetchRequests` (one to find the OLDEST, the second to find the HEAVIEST) I am them taking the `objectID`s for each managed object and adding them to a final `NSFetchRequest` that I am using to setup my `NSFetchedResultsController`.

```
// FETCH REQUEST - OLDEST, HEAVIEST
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"People"];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", IDArray];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

If I "Print the Description" of the final `NSFetchRequest` it does indeed contain 2 pointers to managedObjects.

```
(i.e. [John, 77, 160] [John, 77, 160])
```

My problem seems to be that when I do

```
[[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:nil];
```

the `UITableView` delegate method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *sectionArray = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSUInteger numberOfRows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    NSLog(@"ROWS: %u", numberOfRows);
    return numberOfRows;
}
```

only shows the `numberOfRows` as 1 and only displays a single [John, 77, 160] in my `UITableView`.

Comment: A fetch request does not return duplicate objects. It returns all objects that match the predicate - and that is exactly one object in your case. Why do you need a fetched results controller at all? If you already have 2 objects, put them into an array and display that with a normal table view.

Comment: Hi Martin, thats a good point, the ViewController in question started out with a simple list and a fetched results controller, when I added the extra searches and sorting I kept using the existing fetched results controller. Up until now (testing on 5 people, rather than 500) I have not noticed any problem, I was also not aware that fetch requests do not return duplicate objects. I will look at changing the code to use an array as you suggest. Thank you, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fetch request does not return duplicate objects. It returns all objects that match the predicate. So

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"objectID = %@", oid]
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(objectID = %@) OR (objectID = %@)", oid, oid]
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"objectID IN %@", @[oid, oid]]
```

return all one object with the given object ID (if there is one).

In your case, you have already the objects that you want to display. Therefore I would suggest to store them in an array and use that as table view data source, instead of using a fetched results controller.