# NSPredicate not returning value for each array element swift Core-Data

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am using Core-Data as backing an exchange rate converter, I want to display each countries currency the user requests in a UITableView using NSFetchRequest.

My data model is:

[image]

For example if the user chooses Britain, the US, Zimbabwe, China and Zambia there should be five currencies. That is to say, five rows fetched from core data. The issue is that Zimbabwe also use the USDollar as their currency.

We look up the three digit currency codes

```
threeDigitMain = ["ZAR", "CNY", "USD", "USD", "GBP"]
```

In core data but only get 4 results returned (and thus only four rows in my UITableView). We require the US Dollar to be returned twice!

I suspect the problem is my predicate:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "threedigitcountrycode IN %@", threeDigitMainCountries)
```

I've had a look through documentation, spent some time with different predicates and tried request.returnsDistinctResults = false
but don't know what to set properties to fetch to in this case - over all I cannot seem to get close to the answer. I'd appreciate any help.

To clarify using the following predicate

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "any threedigitcountrycode IN %@", ["USD","USD","USD"])
```

returns a single value, and I would want three.

Comment: The number of results returned by a fetch requests depends on the data you have. If there is just one entity with country code "USD", you will get back one, if there are 100, you will get 100. It has nothing to do with the repetition of the search string in the predicate. You should probably add a relationship from the countries to the rates to get this straight.

Comment: Thanks, I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523234/showing-duplicate-cells-in-uitableview-via-nsfetchedresultscontroller so I now know I can change my model.